# Renaming apk in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, android-productflavors

Some time ago I wrote this script snippet for gradle in order to change the name of the apk that Android Studio generates. It renames the apk with the following data:

- **flavor**
- **build type**
- **version**
- **date**

In the build.gradle:

```
android {
    
    ...
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            ...
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            applicationId "com.feraguiba.myproject"
            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.2.0"
        }
        dev {
            applicationId "com.feraguiba.myproject.dev"
            versionCode 15
            versionName "1.3.6"
        }
    }
    
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def project = "myProject"
            def SEP = "_"
            def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
            def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
            def version = variant.versionName
            def date = new Date();
            def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMyy_HHmm')
    
            def newApkName = project + SEP + flavor + SEP + buildType + SEP + version + SEP + formattedDate + ".apk"
    
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
        }
    }
}
```

If you compile today (26-10-2016) at 10:47, you get the following file name depending on the flavor and build type you have chosen:

- **dev debug**: myProject_**dev_debug_1.3.6**_261016_1047.apk
- **dev release**: myProject_**dev_release_1.3.6**_261016_1047.apk
- **prod debug**: myProject_**prod_debug_1.2.0**_261016_1047.apk
- **prod release**: myProject_**prod_release_1.2.0**_261016_1047.apk

Note: the unaligned version apk name is still the default one.

Althought the renaming works fine and the apk is generated with the correct name, the problem is that sometimes Android Studio is not able to install the apk in the device when I click the "Run project". It complains with the following message:

> The APK file C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\xxx\build\outputs\apk\myProject_dev_debug_1.3.6_191016_1047.apk does not exist on disk.
>
> Error while Installing APK

Why does AS search for "myProject_dev_debug_1.3.6_**19**1016_1047.apk" when the generated one is "myProject_dev_debug_1.3.6_**26**1016_1047.apk" ??? I am missing something and I don't know what.

Doing a "Clean project" or a "Rebuild project" doesn't solve the problem. The only workaround I have found is to modify the script in order to slightly change the name of the apk.

Note: I am using **Android Studio 2.1.3 with gradle 2.1.3**.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle-fury has some hooks to name both artifacts + variants + debug/release + version. Might be worth either borrowing or using it outright.

https://github.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury/blob/master/gradle/maven-support.gradle

disclaimer, i work on it

Comment: It looks cool. But could you show some tips in order to use it?